# AlarmManager repeating only fires once

Tags: java, android

I've set an Alarm in my app to trigger a notification every X minutes. The first time works, but then is not repeating.

The API I'm working on is API 18 (Android 4.3).

**MainActivity.class**

```java
public void setAlarm(Consumo con){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int id = (int) con.getId();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, con.getTime());
        Intent notification = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        notification.putExtra("cadena", con.getName()+
                " "+con.getQuantity()+" "+ con.getType()+" "+con.getPills()+" comprimidos");
        notification.putExtra("id", id);
        PendingIntent pendingNotif = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
                id, notification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingNotif);
    }
```

**AlarmReceiver.class**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static String CHANNEL_ID = "medicinas.android.unex.cum.es.app";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        int id = b.getInt("id");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("id", id);
        TaskStackBuilder tsb = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        tsb.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
        tsb.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        Intent tomada = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        tomada.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        tomada.putExtra("id", id);
        PendingIntent pTomada = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 155, tomada, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = tsb.getPendingIntent(id, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Control de Medicinas")
                .setContentText(intent.getExtras().getString("cadena"))
                .setTicker("¡Hora de tomar la medicina")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.btn_default, "Medicina tomada", pTomada)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "MedicinaNotificacion",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);


    }
}
```

**RECEIVER AFTER MODIFICATIONS**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static String CHANNEL_ID = "medicinas.android.unex.cum.es.app";
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        mContext = context;
        int id = b.getInt("id");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("id", id);
        Consumo con = new Consumo(id, b.getString("name"), b.getInt("quantity"),
                b.getString("type"), b.getInt("pills"), true, b.getInt("time"));
        TaskStackBuilder tsb = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        tsb.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
        tsb.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        Intent tomada = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        tomada.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        tomada.putExtra("id", id);
        String cadena = b.getString("name")+
                " "+b.getInt("quantity")+" "+
                b.getString("type")+" "+b.getInt("pills")+" comprimidos";
        PendingIntent pTomada = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 155, tomada, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = tsb.getPendingIntent(id, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Control de Medicinas")
                .setContentText(cadena)
                .setTicker("¡Hora de tomar la medicina")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.btn_default, "Medicina tomada", pTomada)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "MedicinaNotificacion",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        setAlarm(con);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);


    }

    public void setAlarm(Consumo con){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int id = (int) con.getId();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, con.getTime());
        Intent notification = new Intent(mContext , AlarmReceiver.class);
        notification.putExtra("cadena", con.getName()+
                " "+con.getQuantity()+" "+ con.getType()+" "+con.getPills()+" comprimidos");
        notification.putExtra("id", id);
        notification.putExtra("name", con.getName());
        notification.putExtra("quantity", con.getQuantity());
        notification.putExtra("type", con.getType());
        notification.putExtra("pills", con.getPills());
        notification.putExtra("time", con.getTime());
        Log.i("DEBUG RECEIVER: ", ""+con.getTime());
        PendingIntent pendingNotif = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
                id, notification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, con.getTime()*60*1000, pendingNotif);
    }
}
```

If you need more of the code tell me, I'll add it quickly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingNotif);

and then in onReceive(), call setAlarm() method to set the next alarm

Comment: Mm could be a work around, thanks. But since setAlarm is receiving data from another Activity, that data is lost in the Receiver (can change code to send to it anyway)

Comment: I'm calling setAlarm on the receiver after editing the code to get the object into the receiver but now starts a infinite loop of notifications. Like the trigger time is 1 second, I've added the new Receiver class in the main post. @EricCen

Comment: it must be the value,  con.getTime()*60*1000, in alarmManager.set().  try another value, 30*60*1000, for example to test if it works in every 30 seconds.

Comment: just changed it to calendar.getTimeinMillis() and worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in this line :

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingNotif);
```

Let's assume you want alarm to go off after every 2 minutes, it should be :

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 2*60*1000, pendingNotif);
```

In the above example, replace 2 with whatever minute you want the alarm to go off.

Comment: I'll check, but I think there is no difference, since calendar is set to minutes and then getting time in Millis.

Comment: Same, fires once and then nothing @Azhar92